# Hooking an *unexported* API

Tags: windows, malware, exploit, injection

I want to know is there any way to hook (inline hook) an unexported API of a PE? 
I have this binary (PE 32 bit) which does not uses any DLL (A statically linked binary) and I would like to know what should be the approach to hook a function in this binary (in memory) ?

Following is a thought of mine, but don't know how practical it is? Please let me know your thoughts. Also, please let me know if you have a better solution.

1. Inject DLL to the running binary
2. Injected DLL have to find address of the API to be hooked:

   - search for byte sequence in text section(bytecode of API to be hooked)
3. Add the hook (JMP instruction)

If the above way is the only way to do it. How practical is it? Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [this answer here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/dll-injection-search-for-procedures-variables), but that's pretty much the process you have to take.  The byte sequence should be unique enough.  The preamble for any function will be relatively the same so you might want to skip the first 10 bytes when looking for a pattern.  The answer below by @Atsby outlines the concerns you should address.

Answer (score 2):

> Following is a thought of mine, but don't know how practical it is?

If you don't have access to the source code of the program, you have to make a lot of assumptions about the format of the arguments, etc. And you have to emulate the original behavior of the function in a way that doesn't break the program, or jump back to the (remainder of) the original function after emulating the part of the function you overwrite with the JMP instruction.

You may also have to change the page protection, as program code is usually not writable by default.

Programs that take certain kinds of anti-reverse-engineering measures will be hard to patch in this manner, because they checksum their program code from time to time.

But, for a plain unprotected binary this can work (with requisite effort expended).